# Wix Toolset Custom UI viewer

Tags: xml, user-interface, wix, viewer

I'm building an MSI with Wix (not my first) but now I'm exploring custom UI's.

What I need to know is whether there is a UI viewer to save me building then running the MSI just to check the look. Im currently using VS2012 with the WixToolset plugin.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Yes, kinda. Ditch the stupid MSI concept what they call "UI", and start using Wix Burn to build custom interfaces, using WPF. It will take a little to start, but once you have "template", you'll be able to deliver new installers way faster and have way more control. WPF has "UI viewer".

Comment: Do you know of any good guides on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to install the MSI to see the dialogs. The SuperOrca MSI editor will do it. It's not as good, obviously, because it can't know the behavior of a running dialog, but you can see what it looks like. It's in Tools→Dialog Preview. You still have to build the MSI of course.

Comment: Thank you. I used this method to edit the prebuilt dialogs, and then wrote a post build script to apply the changes.